# How to copy a database in sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb

We have a sharded MongoDB cluster, and we want to the copy current collection.

Is there a special process to do "copy collection" from a sharded cluster?

Comment: is the collection you want to copy sharded or not?

Comment: Any solution to this ? I need to migrate few live collections from one cluster to other. what are my options ? original collections are sharded and we want to move them as is in sharded form to other cluster? [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371189/mongo-db-copying-live-sharded-collection-from-one-cluster-to-other)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 3.2 and above you can use mongodump (Docs found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)) and mongorestore (Docs found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)).  Note that the docs state it can be problematic to backup sharded databases.  You will have to consider how in sync you want the data and take proper action.  Mongo docs going deeper on that can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-database-dumps/).

Mongo 3.2 supports backing up sharded clusters with a snapshot, if you want to use that option check out the docs found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-filesystem-snapshots/).

Finally, restoring the databases using the various processes can be found on Mongo's docs on restoring sharded clusters found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-sharded-cluster/).  Again this will differ based on what version you're running, so be careful to read the docs.  They all go through the process in depth and clearly.

I thought you could use copyDatabase, but the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) state that it does not work with sharded databases.

Comment: The OP concern is to copy the only 'collection' in 'sharded cluster' environment.

Answer (score 0):

As per **MongoDB BOL** [cloneCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/#dbcmd.cloneCollection) Copies a collection from a `remote mongod` instance to the current `mongod` instance. `cloneCollection` creates a collection in a database with the same name as the remote collection’s database. `cloneCollection` takes the following form:

```
{ cloneCollection: "<namespace>",
  from: "<hostname>",
  query: { <query> }
}
```

**Behavior**

[mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/#bin.mongos) does not support db.cloneCollection().

When copying the specified collection, `db.cloneCollection()` uses the same database name in the from server as the destination database. If the collection does not exist, `db.cloneCollection()` fails.

`db.cloneCollection()` cannot be used if the from server has [authorization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/) enabled.

Changed in **version 3.0**: If the given [collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-collection) already exists in the destination [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) instance, db.cloneCollection() returns an error.

**Example**

```
use users
db.cloneCollection('mongodb.example.net:27017', 'profiles',
                    { 'active' : true } )
```

This operation copies the profiles collection from the users database on the server at mongodb.example.net into the users database on the local server. The operation only copies documents that satisfy the query `{ 'active' : true }`.

Comment: As mentioned in the `Behavior` it will not work for mongos hence sharded collections which is what the original questions asks for